# Format for multi-level json and data extraction method with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My apologies, but I am not well versed in json.  We are currently using a single level json file for date information, one file per tour package.  These are fetched via js then processed and inserted into the appropriate spots on the webpage.  What we would like to do is combined all the tours date information, plus some additional details, into a single json file that once fetched is cached on the browser for a few hours.  Basically ending up with a local flat file "database" with all tours for js to access.

Doing the single level json was fairly straight forward, but combining it into multiple levels is more daunting.  I am wondering:
  1) if there is a specific format for the data as outlined below?
  2) how to use js to extract the data from that format?

Each tour is designated by a numerical id and has number of values.  So should this first level be one or two levels (this is only the data concept, not json code):

```
tours -> tour_id, price1, price2, price3, duration, level, dates

tours -> tour_id -> price1, price2, price3, duration, level, dates
```

The dates value will have multiple dates each with several values:

```
dates -> date1, date2, date3, date4, etc

each date has -> trip_code, start_date, end_date, price, spaces
```

The basic functionality will be, when the page is loaded js will read the tour value from the page, then find the appropriate tour within the json file. The general values will be extracted by one function and simply inserted into the page as is using innerHTML.  The date values will be used by a different function to build strings and then those strings likewise inserted into the page.

As I read through available info, I find some folks use only braces, some use braces & brackets, various suggestions for extraction, etc. I appreciate any help towards which format / extraction method would be preferable.  And by preferrable, I mean whichever format / method puts the least workload on the browser.  Having a slightly larger file size due to extra braces or brackets is fine if it reduces the js overhead and speeds up the finished page.

While it is probably of no consequence to the answer, the json file will be built by PHP and saved as a static file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the multi-level object in the form

`multiLevel = { [tour_id]: yourOriginal1LevelObject}`

For retrieving the tour you can use

`const tour = multiLevel[tour_id]`

or using destructuring

`const {tour_id: tour} = multiLevel`